# docker-compose container - nginx host not found in upstream

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

So I was trying to create a nginx container which points to another container running nginx, which is a frontend container. I have my `default.conf` file for the nginx container and frontend container, its own conf file.

`docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    restart: always
    hostname: frontend
    build:
      context: ./demo-project
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -qO- http://frontend/ping || exit 1"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 30
    networks:
      demo-net:
        aliases:
          - frontend

  proxy:
    hostname: proxy
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      frontend:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      demo-net:
        aliases:
          - proxy
networks:
  demo-net:
    driver: bridge
```

my nginx container `default.conf` file is :

```
upstream frontend_servers {
  server frontend:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass frontend_servers;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

the Dockerfile of nginx is :

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

The error I'm facing is

```
[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "frontend:80" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:26
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "frontend:80" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:26
```

I have tried to create a docker container with this command `docker run --rm -d --network demo_demo-networks --hostname proxy --name my_nginx nginx` taking a shell of this command and tried to `ping frontend` and it gives the success response. Same case the image generated from docker-compose I tried to run it manually and still getting this error.

Also tried adding health check and it shows the frontend container is healthy. Is this issue arises because container tried to call the frontend even before connecting with the network?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to expose the port 80 on frontend.

Comment: Tried it no luck

Comment: can you please share the dockerfile for frontend as well, so that we can replicate the error ?